# with JSTL how can I determine which variable is null before a forEach

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have two lists. only one can be not null at a time.

I want to iterate over the one that's not null but I don't want to use `<c:choose>` because I would have to repeat the code in `<c:when> and <c:otherwise>`

how can I do something like

if list1 is not null then iterate over list 1 otherwise list2

```
<c:forEach items="${list1}" var="staffMember">

>html here that I don't want to repeat in my source code...<
```

Comment: How about not doing this work in the template, and setting a single list on the Java side, where such work belongs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ternary operator to access the right list within `<c:forEach>`:

```
<c:forEach items="${(empty list1) ? list2 : list1}" var="staffMember">
    ....
</c:forEach>
```

Of course, it implies that both list containt instances of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use  then you can try .
And check in that for empty. some thing like this..

```
    <c:if test="{not empty testList1}"> Execute First</c:if>  
    <c:if test="{not empty testList2}"> Execute Second</c:if>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${not empty testList1}">
    <c:set var="TargetList" value="${testList1}"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="TargetList" value="$testList2}"/>
  </c:choose>

  <c:forEach items="${TargetList}" var="staffMember">
    ...
  </c:forEach>
```